# How do I set up a network share to be always accessible while roaming?

Tags: linux, networking, nas, samba, nat

At home I have a Raspberry Pi which I use as a NAS and [torrent box](https://www.howtogeek.com/142044/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-always-on-bittorrent-box/). I would like to set up a network share on it that I can access from outside my LAN so that I can stream music and video when I'm at school, work or otherwise roaming.

I want to be able to set it up so that my laptop can automatically mount it whenever an Internet connection is available, and so that I can suspend and resume without it breaking the mounts.

Samba seems to work great inside my LAN, but it's supposedly not a good idea to share it to the Internet.

Encryption of the data is not a priority, but authentication is of course necessary to protect my data.

If possible I would like it to use as little computing power as possible on the server since the Raspberry Pi is pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an SSH server on your Raspberry Pi by following [guide like this](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2012/05/29/enabling-ssh-on-debian-raspberry-pi/). And, set up a public/private keypair.

For auto login rather than using your user/pass every time you want to log in from trusted devices. Once, that's all setup, all you need is  `sshfs`.

Install `sshfs` on your laptop and mount your home directory through the `sshfs` command to your laptop.

*SSH provides secure encrypted communications between two untrusted hosts over an insecure network* so all your communication would be encrypted.